# How to use getStaticProps or getServerSiteProps in Next.js to deal with object in local file?

Tags: next.js

I have a local file located at ./public/clients.js, which contains an array of user objects. I want to use Next.js's getStaticProps or getServerSideProps to fetch and work with this data in my application.

Here's a simplified version of the data structure in clients.js:

```
export const users = new Promise((resolve) =>
  resolve([
    {
      id: 1,
      firstName: "Bob",
      lastName: "Dole"
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      firstName: "Ann",
      lastName: "Pell"
    },
    {
      id: 3,
      firstName: null,
      lastName: "Wess"
    },
 ])
);
```

How can I write the syntax for getStaticProps or getServerSideProps to retrieve this data from clients.js and use it in my Next.js application?

I'm specifically looking for guidance on how to import the data from the local file and pass it as props to a React component.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When we use **clinets.js** file as is we will get the error:

[image]

After modified **clients.js**:

```
export const users = [
  {
    id: 1,
    firstName: "Bob",
    lastName: "Dole",
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    firstName: "Ann",
    lastName: "Pell",
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    firstName: null,
    lastName: "Wess",
  },
];
```

**example2.js** (home page) I used in this case a little bit of [`tailwindcss`](https://tailwindcss.com/):

```
import ItemsList from "../components/ItemsList";
import { users } from "../public/clients";

function example2({ data }) {
  console.log(data);
  return (
    <div className="flex h-screen items-center justify-center flex-col gap-1">
      <h1 className="text-3xl text-green-700 font-bold">
        getStaticProps - example
      </h1>
      <ItemsList data={data} />
    </div>
  );
}

export const getStaticProps = async () => {
  return {
    props: {
      data: { users },
    },
  };
};

export default example2;
```

**ItemsList.js** component:

```
import Items from "./Items";

function ItemsList({ data: { users } }) {
  return (
    <>
      <ul>
        {users.map((event) => (
          <Items
            key={event.id}
            id={event.id}
            firstName={event.firstName}
            lastName={event.lastName}
          />
        ))}
      </ul>
    </>
  );
}

export default ItemsList;
```

**Items.js** component:

```
function Items({ id, firstName, lastName }) {
  return (
    <div>
      <small>{id}</small>
      <h1>{firstName}</h1>
      <h2>{lastName}</h2>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Items;
```

---

**Output**:

[image]

*Tested with: "next": "12.0.7", "react": "17.0.2", "tailwindcss": "^3.0.5"*